# How to link 32-bit framework for 64-bit compiler (Architecture)

Tags: ios, ios7

I have old app which has linked few frameworks. Those frameworks haven't 64-bit version. Is it possible to build the app with those frameworks in 64-bit mode? Thank you for reply!

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "no". If the library you need to link is `open source` then your best bet is probably to compile it yourself in to a `64-bit` library; otherwise you can contact the vendor of the library and request the status of a `64-bit` build.